# Spring Autowired with abstract inheritance error

Tags: spring, tomcat, inheritance, autowired

Consider this situation:

I have a class A and B and C.

Class B extends abstract class A and class C want to use class B as a 
member to perform operations.

```
@Service
public abstract class A{

}

@Component
public class B extends A{

}


@Service
Public class C {  
  private class B b;

  @Autowired
  public C(Class B b){  // constructor
    this.b = b;
  }    

  private void setB(B b){
    this.b = b;
  }

  private B getB(){
    return b;
  }
}
```

When ever I try to do a component scan, the tomcat does not load.
I have already successful inject beans in this way for non inherit objects.

The error I receive is a listen start error:

> Jun 14, 2015 12:09:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart Jun 14, 2015 12:09:04 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [] startup failed due to previous errors Jun 14, 2015 12:09:05 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have traced the problem when I am adding this line in the code:  HttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(); even if this piece of code does not run when adding autowired I am getting the error, without autowire it works. kinda weird I have to admit. I am unable to find any logs in tomcat related to this.

Comment: By the way I am adding it to class A inside an unused method.

Answer (score 0):

There was a dependencies issue I was able to print the tomcat stack trace by adding a logging.properties file in the WEB-INF/conf

with this value:

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler